# websocket stomp in spring over sockjs redirects to http protocol while the origin is https in pivotal web services

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp, sockjs, pivotal-web-services

I am developing a spring web chat application using stomp and `sockjs`. I uploaded the application in pivotal web services. I understand that it uses a different port i.e. 4443. Once I run the application the `websocket` losts connection to undefined

The following error comes into the console:
Opening Web Socket...

WebSocket connection to

`'wss://homeworkpavilion.cfapps.io:4443/chat/193/dqu_2erz/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302`

```
POST https://homeworkpavilion.cfapps.io/chat/193/_bhfpyma/xhr_streaming 500 (Internal Server Error)

POST https://homeworkpavilion.cfapps.io/chat/193/nys00vmj/xhr 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Whoops! Lost connection to undefined

Pls help, this stuff is reaaaalyy bugging me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no permission to redirect to different port. You can bypass this restriction by setting all origins to allowed when registering your stomp endpoints.
I want to point out, that this is a very bad solution. You should take advantage of proxies, but I lack information here to help you with that.

Here is the code you might find useful:

```
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
   registry.addEndpoint("/your_endpoint").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually did that. But now it bring the a 403 error, Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403

Comment: There is also a nice tutorial of this on official spring website here: [https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/20/the-resource-server-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-iii](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/20/the-resource-server-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-iii)